# Freeware to speed up Windows PC

Tags: windows-7, optimization

My Windows PC is running slow. Looking for freeware recommendations to fix the problem and keep my 3-year-old PC running smooth.

Comment: Seriously, reinstall Windows from scratch. Avoid to install any bloatware / "browser toolbars" / "tuning software" afterwards. Oh, and consider to exchange the hard disk by an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

[Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) is the only cleaning software that I would use, nearly all of the other tuning software installs software that actually *slows* your machine down. But your best bet is a reinstall, maybe with Ubuntu? If you have to stick with installing Windows, once it is installed ensure that you have Windows Automatic Updates active (and that your machine is currently up to date), and use [MS Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/security-essentials-download) as a virus checker.

Or, in addition to the SSD suggestion, maybe your PC just needs more memory? If memory is low then the hard disk will be thrashed swapping page files in and out of memory.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree with re-install